# Read dBase III file that contains strings in utf-16 LE format with C# and OleDb

Tags: c#, character-encoding, oledb, dbase

I want to read a dBase III file that contains character columns with utf-16 little-endian encoded strings. This is done with c# and the System.Data.OleDb classes.

My code looks like this

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=\"dBASE III;\";Data Source=" + filePath + ";"
using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName) + "]";
    var adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
dataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

In a character-column with the value `John`, a hex-editor shows me `4A 00 6F 00 68 00 6E 00` in the dbf-file (which is `John`, but after each character-byte there is a null-byte). I assume the used encoding in the dbf-file for strings is utf-16 little endian. The default string-handling results in only the first character, it ends with the first null-byte, so I only see `J` as a result.

How can I get the encoding right? Is it a thing I need to tell the OleDb connection, or do I have to convert each character-field byte-wise manually after reading the data?

Is there a better way to read dbase-files?

Comment: I solved the issue by creating classes that read the files, inspired by https://github.com/henck/dBASE.NET.